# TensorFlow.js on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

Does TensorFlow.js support Internet Explorer (not Edge)?

It seems that TensorFlowJS requires asynchronous support (Promise/Async/Then/etc). This doesn't seem like an *necessary* requirement for the library. I mean, it should be possible to apply a neural network synchronously even if it freezes the browser for a couple seconds. Any suggestions on how to run tf.loadModel() synchronously?

I ask because I'm trying to run a model on a hospital network that is locked into IE 11.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem like an necessary requirement for the library" .? If a library uses promise/async then you will have to load a pollyfill before the library is used, if its not a OOTB in the browser.

Comment: I mean it *shouldn't* be a requirement, since it isn't essential to applying an ML model. IMHO, TFJS should not require functionality other that that which is necessary to actually train or apply a model. The end-developer can augment as needed to do things asynchronously, if desired. IE still has a huge market share and is fast enough for model deployment.

Answer (score 0):

We use Promises pretty heavily in the library, have you tried using a Promise polyfill?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Comment: Hey, I'm new to JavaScript, and I spent the weekend learning about Babel, WebPack, and Polyfills. I'm about 80% there...will accept answer if I get it working.

Comment: You should try using Parcel if you are new. I recommend starting with one of the directories inside our examples repo, you can just copy paste it and you should be able to get something working: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples